# Number of paths of length $5$ in a $5$-regular graph with $m$ edges and girth at least $6$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a $5$-regular graph with $m$ edges and girth at least $6$. To find the number of paths of length $5$.

---

A regular graph is a graph where each vertex has the same number of neighbours.

The girth of a graph is the length of a shortest cycle contained in the graph.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: number of paths comes from powers of adjacency matrix.

Answer (score 1):

By the handshaking lemma there are $\frac{2m}5$ vertices. Since the girth is at least $6$, we won't have to worry about running back onto ourselves; choosing a vertex and picking a neighbour five times will yield all paths exactly *twice* (we may trace the same path both ways), so the number of paths is
$$\frac12\cdot\frac{2m}5\cdot5\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4=256m$$